# Can anyone explain about how this recursive function works in c++?

Tags: c++

I have been new to programming and solving C++ questions of Deitel book for a while now and I got confused when imagining this recursive function in which an array of 10 elements and the first element number(current = 0) is sent to the function.

My question is after executing the someFunction function inside the if block, does the function return back to the function definition again or the execution continues with the next statement ?

```
void someFunction(const array<int , arraySize>& b, size_t current)
    {
        if (current < b.size())
            {
                someFunction(b, current + 1);
                cout << b[current] << " ";  
            }
    }
```

Comment: You can run this code under a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: I runned already, i have been trying to imagine the code in my mind, I want to make sure how it works.

Comment: If you step through it one line at a time in the debugger you can see what happens on each line. Look at the variables, the callstack and the flow after executing each line. Don't just run it to the completion in 1 step, actively debug.

Comment: I completely forgot that, thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All function calls work the same way. After returning from the function call the execution resumes with the next statement after the function call.

Recursive function calls are no different, in that respect. The only difference between a recursive and a non-recursive function call is which function gets called: the same one or a different one.

Note that the function call ***itself*** starts executing the function again, but after it returns the same thing happens as when returning from any other function call.